# Generating random numbers in order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, random

Is there a way to get random numbers from a list of numbers and then put them in order?

For example if I want 4 numbers between 1 and 12 how can I get these numbers in ascending order?

EDIT: I need the numbers to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the random values in an array and then use PHP's sort function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

```
$numbers = range(1, 12); 
shuffle($numbers); 
$numbers=array_slice($numbers, 0, 4); 
sort($numbers);
```

Comment: In a table?!  Why so overkill when you can simply store the values in an array?

Comment: whoops huge typo. rushing my answer out a little too fast haha. edited

Comment: No problem.  Other than that, good answer. :)  Informative, but doesn't just give it to the "asker."

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately it doesn't check for duplicate values which I should have put in the original question  :(

Comment: Thanks for that; your first answer pointed me in the right direction so I came up with this $numbers = range(1, 12);
  shuffle($numbers);
  $numbers=array_slice($numbers, 0, 4);
  sort($numbers);

Comment: I was gonna say that, range + shuffle work well if you need a randomized list without repeated values (both operations are computational heavy though afaicr, careful if you plan to run them several times)

Comment: Even better! updated! Hopefully others will find this helpful as well

Answer (score 3):

```
$output = array();
for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++){
   $output[] = mt_rand(1, 12);
}
sort($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$y=array();
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){$y[$i]=mt_rand(1,12);}
sort($y);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this up, adding to array, then sorting later on.

**foreach** and **range** would be easier to read, so easier to maintain :)

```
<?php
$b1 = 1;
$b2 = 12;

$nums = array();
foreach(range(1,4) as $i){
   $nums[] = rand($b1,$b2);
}
sort($nums);
var_dump($nums);
```

For more info about sort
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: `foreach(range(1,4)` --- why not `for`? It's an overkill to generate an array for that. PS: nope, it is not easy to read and definitely not easy to maintain

Comment: forloop is ok too but I guess its just preference that we find this approach easier to read.

Comment: I dont think its overkill though, unless you're using this in some very big loop, math operations.

Comment: "we find this approach easier to read" -- it is very strange. Because every single imperative programming language has `for` and everyone knows how to use it, while `foreach + range` is terribly not intuitive solution

Comment: If you want to use it anyway - why not generate the `$nums` and traverse over it? In this case we at least don't create useless array